# How do i create a range for each trading day using the opening time's high and low?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

How do i get hold of today's 00:00 (open time) high and low as x and y so that i can be able to create a vertical line between them? I am trying to create a range for each trading day as pictured, any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This was the closest thing I could do.

It is not possible to do it in the only line of the sail without the line being infinite as in your example, so to make it from a certain height you must make 2 plots and fill them.

You can also modify the position of the line if it does not match your time zone.

[image: This is how its looks]

```
//@version=5
indicator("Keiden vertical line", overlay=true)

tHour = input.int(0, maxval=23, minval=0, title="Open Hour", group="Enter 
the open hour of the day")

plotTime = hour == tHour and minute == 0 ? true : false
hValuePlot = ta.valuewhen(plotTime, high, 0)
lValuePlot = ta.valuewhen(plotTime, low, 0)

H = plot(hValuePlot, color=color.new(color.blue, plotTime[1]?0:100))
L = plot(lValuePlot, color=color.new(color.blue, plotTime[1]?0:100))

fill(H, L, color=color.new(color.blue, plotTime[1]?0:100))
```